# C++ regexp to parsing nested struct

Tags: c++, regex

I have a string formatted as follows permanent way:

```
{
  First nested string;
  {
    Second nested string;
  }
}
```

Nesting may be arbitrary depth. Each sub-element is formatted closing brace, adding two spaces to the previous level of nesting and closing brace. I want to receive the regular expression allows to obtain nested data. For example, for the above example the result should be:

```
First nested string;
{
  Second nested string;
}
```

I wrote the following code that allows you to parse strings in only one line, as a symbol '.' is any character except a newline.

```
regex regEx("\\s*\\{\\s*(.*?)\\s*\\}\\s*");
string testInput = 
"{\n"
"  First nested string;\n"
"  {\n"
"    Second nested string;\n"
"  }\n"
"}\n";
smatch match;
if (regex_search(testInput, match, regEx))
{
    auto result = match[1].str();
}
```

What regular expression will make it so that I can receive nested data?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: None. What you have there is not a regular language, and while some regular expression libraries extend regular expressions into the realm of context-free languages such as this one, the C++ standard library does not support recursion. You may be interested in [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) to parse this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex implementation from the C++ standard library does not support recursion, which would be needed to match nested structures.

Like Wintermute said in the comments, nested structures such as this are not a regular language, and you need other tools.

**FYI**, you can use [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) or [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) to match the following pattern:

```
\{(?:[^{}]++|(?R))*\}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nO8pS3/1)

This is a pretty simple recursive pattern. Some explanations:

- `[^{}]++` matches anything but `{` or `}` *possessively*.
- `(?R)` recurses the entire pattern
- the `*` quantifier is applied over the inner possessive `++` quantifier, which prevents [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

The thing is, this will only help with **matching** properly nested constructs. It won't really help you with **parsing**. Regexes aren't really the right tool for such a job, a parser would be much more appropriate.

If you *still* want to go the regex way, you'll have to expand the pattern to match the constructs more precisely. If using PCRE you may want to use the *callout* mechanism to extract information from the pattern *while* the engine is performing the match. But like I said, just write a parser.